# QCamera не работает вне IDE

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, камера

Использую Qt Creator, Qt 5.7. Компилятор mingw53_32. OS - windows 7. На других 
Проблема при работе с веб-камерой. 
При запуске программы внутри IDE, всё впорядке, находит все камеры, их описание, хорошо захватывает с них изображение. 
Но после компиляции проекта и переноса в папку со всеми зависимостями не обнаруживается никаких камер и с них, соответственно нельзя захватить изображение.

При этом не удалось даже удачно запустить вне IDE пример от самого Qt. Анологично моей программе - в IDE работает отлично, вне - не обнаруживает камер.

ПК скомпилированная программа так же не находит камер.

Comment: Добавьте запись в лог фал и запустите отдельно, там вам будет понятно на каком этапе произошла ошибка. Может быть проблема в каких-то настроках среды, не инициализированные переменные, относительных путях к файлу.

Comment: а plugins\mediaservice\ на месте?

Comment: Да, не хватало этого плагина. Добавил mediaservice в папку с программой и заработло. Спасибо.

Отправь в ответы. Отмечу как правильный